# Asp.Net tab control not visible

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Problem is simple the tab control shows in design mode but is not getting shown when viewing from browser. Enable and Visible is true. Although the controls are getting rendered and I can see the HTML.

I am using .NET 3.5 AND TOOLKIT version is 3.5.4xxxx

Page code is like this. Right now ther is nothing in the code behind.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" CodeFile="OrderDetailsPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="OrderDetailsPage" Title="Order Page" EnableViewState="true" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

    <div id="pagetitle">
        <asp:Literal ID="caseHeader" runat="server">Loyalty Management Partner Portal</asp:Literal>
    </div>

    <!--CONTENT CONTAINER-->

    <div id="content-container-two-column">

    <!--CONTENT SIDE 1 COLUMN-->

        <div id="content-side-two-column" height="780px">
            <ul class="list-of-links">
                <li><a href="../../LMS/Partners/PartnersHomePage.aspx">Loyalty Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="../../LMS/Partners/OrderStatusPage.aspx">Orders Status Page</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br />
        </div>

        <!--CENTER COLUMN-->

        <div id="content-main-two-column">
            <strong class="headerText">Order Details Page</strong>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h3 class="helpText">
                Provide details of Order. You can update order status, Add notes to orders.
            </h3>
            <asp:Label ID="lblError" CssClass="error" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" />
            <hr />

            <asp:TabContainer ID="tabContainer1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="250px">

                <asp:TabPanel runat="server" ID="tabOrder" HeaderText="Order">                    
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" width="15%">
                                    <b>Order No.</b>
                                </td>
                                <td width="85%" colspan="4" valign="top">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblOrderNo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:TabPanel>

                <asp:TabPanel ID="tabOrderDetails" runat="server" HeaderText="Ordered Items">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentTemplate>

                </asp:TabPanel>

                <asp:TabPanel ID="tabNotes" runat="server" HeaderText="Notes">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:TabPanel>

            </asp:TabContainer>            
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: All this description is very nice but you actually forgot to post the most important part which holds the key => your code, or more precisely a stripped down version of your code that exhibits this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the Ajax toolkit and reinstall it to make it working.